# p4python: perforce: giving sync command throwing error-: rename: failed to rename <filename> after 10 attempts

Tags: perforce, p4python

i am syncing my workspace file to a previous revision by using sync command as : p4_object.run("sync", "-f", "--parallel=0", "c:\Users\agrahari\Desktop\give\first\test_2.txt#2")
it is throwing error: rename: failed to rename c:\Users\agrahari\Desktop\give\first\test_2.txt after 10 attempts: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

file is there in workspace but with revision #3 synced.
please suggest what to do to get it synced with revision #2

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you simply run `p4 sync -f test_2.txt#2` from the command line? That is, can you verify whether it is or isn't  something that you are doing in your P4Python program? In general, that '10 attempts' error arises when the file is in use by some other program at the moment that 'p4 sync' wants to replace the file's contents.

Answer (score 4):

Got the solution. issue was I was not closing the file handler before committing a sync command. thanks.

Comment: Note: this can also mean that you have something else open that uses some of the files that are affected (e.g. the text file is open in an editor, or a binary asset is currently being used.)

Answer (score 0):

If You are getting this error while Unshelve then select Overwrite option or manually delete the file from explorer and proceed with unshelve